# PWA userChoice promise never resolves

Tags: android, google-chrome, progressive-web-apps

I'm trying to implement tracking of user choices after `beforeinstallprompt` fired and [mini info bar](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/06/a2hs-updates#the_mini-infobar) appears. 
Here is a snippet from MDN on [BeforeInstallPromptEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/BeforeInstallPromptEvent)

```
window.addEventListener("beforeinstallprompt", function(e) { 
  // log the platforms provided as options in an install prompt 
  console.log(e.platforms); // e.g., ["web", "android", "windows"] 
  e.userChoice.then(function(outcome) { 
    console.log(outcome); // either "accepted" or "dismissed"
  }, handleError); 
});
```

And this is my implementation basing on Google's [example](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/06/a2hs-updates#showing-the-prompt)

```
window.addEventListener('beforeinstallprompt', (e) => {
  ga(`${experimentName}.send`, 'speedlink_offer', 'show', 'true');
  e.userChoice.then((choice) => {
    if (choice.outcome === 'accepted') {
      ga(`${experimentName}.send`, 'speedlink_offer', 'click', 'true');
    } else {
      ga(`${experimentName}.send`, 'speedlink_offer', 'close', 'true');
    }
  } );
});
```

But promise `userChoice` never resolves. Why it doesn't resolve after a user clicks on Cancel or Add button? Is it a bug or am I missing something?
[image]

PS.
I've found that if you capture user action (e.g. click) and execute `event.prompt()` then `userChoice` will be resolved. But it will be done independently of user interaction with "native" Chrome's [mini-info bar](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/06/a2hs-updates#the_mini-infobar).

PPS.
Chrome version on my Android device is `70.0.3538.110`

Comment: Sorry to resurrect, but I am experiencing the same issue, did you ever resolve this?

Comment: No, unfortunately this wasn't solved.

Comment: I actually solved the problem of you still care lol.

Comment: So, how did you solve it?

Answer (score 2):

I went through the docs and was facing the same issue. So, when you call `prompt` on the saved prompt, you actually get a `Promise<UserChoice>` where `UserChoice` is

```
type UserChoice = {
  outcome: "accepted" | "dismissed";
  platform: string;
};
```

This is not from the docs but my own typeScript implementation. So yeah, instead of waiting for userChoice to get resolved, check the promise from `prompt`.

Here is the implementation from my app.

```
return prompt
  .prompt()
  .then(userChoice => {
    console.log("Prompted, result = ", userChoice);
    switch (userChoice.outcome) {
      case "accepted":
        analytics_track(key, userChoice);
        break;
      case "dismissed":
        analytics_track(key, userChoice);
        break;
    }
  })
  .catch(reason => {
    console.error("Could not prompt", reason);
  });
```